# Que pasa si modifico las cookies

Tags: html, web, cookies

tengo entendido que las cookies son información que una web guarda en nuestro pc, entiendo que sirve para que no tengamos que iniciar sesión, y eso me lleva a preguntarme, si yo modifico la cookie, puedo hackear la web? Una pregunta muy tonta: que pasa si localizo la cookie y me pongo como usuario con privilegios en la cookie? Es decir, que mecanismos tienen las webs para validar que la información de su cookie es correcta?

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. Todo depende de que datos entan guardados en la cookie, como se guardaron esos datos, como se creo la cookie y como la "web" valida los datos en la cookie.

Comment: Te reto a que lo intentes. Aunque hay servidores cuya seguridad es patética, la mayoría de los serios usa cookies encriptadas con los algoritmos bien fuertes que además expiran y se renuevan mucho antes de que cualquiera pueda "adivinarlo" por fuerza bruta. Además que se asocian generalmente con tu navegador, tu ip, tu nombre de usuario, etc. Te reto a que hagas un experimento. Entra a un sitio web por chrome por ejemplo, regístrate, copia las cookies y ahora abre el mismo sitio por Firefox y créalas ahí. ¿Te autenticaste?

Comment: Muchos sitios te lo permitirán, pero los realmente serios verificarán el `fingerprint ` de tu navegador (User Agent, version, resolution, language etc) antes de dejarte pasar. Respuesta corta: Depende de la web. De poder puedes, aunque en estos días la seguridad se está tomando muy en serio, así que te será bastante difícil. Sin contar que no sé como vas a "adivinar" las cookies de usuarios con privilegios administrativos. De cualquier forma, es una pregunta muy genérica, la veo más en un sitio como quora que acá. Lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas cookies para mantener la sesión, realmente lo que guardas en tu navegador es un "token": un valor que puede ser aleatorio y que sirve de identificador. Por ejemplo: el usuario se loga con su dirección de correo y su password y la aplicación guarda lo siguiente:

> "El usuario X tiene la sesión `c32d8b45-92fe-44f6-8b61-42c2107dfe87`" (esto se llama [UUID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal)).

Ese valor se te devuelve en la respuesta para que se guarde en una cookie. Ahora, cada petición que hagas incluirá ese valor y la web comprobará en su colección de sesiones activas a qué usuario pertenece ese valor. La posibilidad de que generes un UUID válido al azar y que se esté usando en ese momento es tan pequeña que podemos considerarla 0 (hay 3,4 × 10<sup>38</sup> posibles valores, así que aunque cada habitante del planeta estuviera usando un valor distinto a la vez, la probabilidad de que encuentres uno al azar es de menos de 1 entre 10<sup>28</sup> (10 mil cuatrillones).

Además, se podría "firmar" ese UUID para comprobar que no se ha modificado, con lo que esa posibilidad desparecería del todo.

En resumen: la infomación que una aplicación correctamente implementada guarda en el lado del cliente (navegador) nunca debe permitir que un usuario pueda usarla para saltarse la seguridad.

Otra opción es usar un JWT, que puede guardar información del usuario pero no permite tampoco ser modificado en el lado del cliente.